# How to distribute several values of a variable from another data.frame, considering the different groups in R

Tags: r

I would like to distribute several values of a variable in a data.frame from another data.frame, considering the different groups.

More specifically, I have the following data.frame:

```
    structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), District = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Value = c("90", 
"700", "2500", "4500", "14000", "14500", "900", "1750", "5000", 
"70", "29000", "10000", "NA", "90", "4000", "NA", "7000", "1000"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

And from the following data.frame:

```
structure(list(Country = c("A", "B", "C"), p1 = c(80, 90, 110
), p2 = c(100, 110, 200), p3 = c(900, 1000, 3000), p4 = c(1600, 
2000, 5000), p5 = c(2000, 4500, 7000), p6 = c(3000, 7000, 9000
), p7 = c(5000, 13000, 15000), p8 = c(9000, 15000, 20000), p9 = c(15000, 
20000, 25000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I would like to create a `level` variable so that its output is as follows:

```
structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), District = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Value = c("90", 
"700", "2500", "4500", "14000", "14500", "900", "1750", "5000", 
"70", "29000", "10000", "NA", "90", "4000", "NA", "7000", "1000"
), Level = c("p2", "p3", "p6", "p7", "p9", "p9", "p3", "p4", 
"p6", "p1", "p9", "p7", "NA", "p1", "p4", "NA", "p5", "p3")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I tried using the findInterval function, but I didn't get success. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

With `findInterval` an option is

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>%
     mutate(Level = names(df2)[-1][findInterval(as.numeric(Value), 
    df2 %>%
      filter(Country == .y$Country) %>%
      select(-Country) %>%
      unlist) + 1])) %>%
  ungroup
```